Do OLAP Cube architecture include the unrequired tables to the queries?
I have an OLAP Cube created by relating about 40 tables(5 facts and 35 dimensions).
The question im interested in is if I query (select count(*) from tableA) to the SQL Server, should the result differ from the result of the equivalent query on the PowerBI server queried on the OLAP Cube?
For example :
Table A [Acol1, Acol2, Acol3] Table B [Bcol1, Bcol2, Bcol3] Table C [Ccol1, Ccol2, Ccol3] Table D [Dcol1, Dcol2, Dcol3]
And the architecture looks like:
A<->B<->C->D...
AA<->B<->E...
And so on.
The query on the SQL Server:
select count(*) from tableA
The query on the SQL Server:
MDXFormat(select count(*) from tableA)   (I do not know how to write MDX sadly)
select count(*) from tableA
The output : 950
MDXFormat(select count(*) from tableA)
The output : 952
I expected them to be the same, but there is a slight difference for some reason. I think OLAP Cube and the SQL Server do not have the same data. What I expect from OLAP Cube is to include only the related tables to the query, but I'm not sure if that's the case or not.
